# Discord.js SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':' when making activities line

Tags: discord.js

I need help fixing this. It looks okay to me, however im new to this. Any fixes?

```
discord: {
        token: 'TOKEN',
        prefix: '?',
        changingActivity:
            activities: ('with Mantis Mod', 'over Mantis Fam', 'Mantis'),
            types: ['PLAYING', 'WATCHING', 'LISTENING'],
```

Comment: It doesn't look okay at all. What is `changingActivity`? Is it meant to be an object?

Comment: Its meant to make it say different activitys ever so often

Answer (score 0):

`changingActivity` doesn't have a value. Because of this, the compiler thinks that `activities` is the value and the colon after that is unexpected. If you meant to put it inside an object, you forgot to put a set of braces.

```json
discord: {
    token: 'TOKEN',
    prefix: '?',
    changingActivity: {
        activities: ('with Mantis Mod', 'over Mantis Fam', 'Mantis'),
        types: ['PLAYING', 'WATCHING', 'LISTENING'],
    }
}
```